# Trouble redirecting homepage url in wordpress but keep directory urls from redirecting

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-302

I am using a subdomain to host do pdfs for client that doesn't want to give access to their website back end.

In the .htaccess file, how do I 302 re-direct the homepage *subdomain.domain.co.uk* to *www.clientwebsite.co.uk*, so that I don't need to create a landing page, but stop *subdomain.domain.co.uk/folder/file.pdf* from re directing too?

I have tried these so far with no avail:

```
# BEGIN 302 Redirects
Redirect 302 / https://www.clientwebsite.co.uk/
# END 302 Redirects
```

and

```
# BEGIN 302 Redirects
Redirect 302 http://subdomain.domain.co.uk https://www.clientwebsite.co.uk/
# END 302 Redirects
```

and

```
# BEGIN 302 Redirects
Redirect 302 http://subdomain.domain.co.uk/index.php https://www.clientwebsite.co.uk/
# END 302 Redirects
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry but why 302? If you want to always serve via the new domain, you need to use 301. Anyway, you can swap the type between 301 and 302 in the example below.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

The first line is really important. You need to read through [this whole guide](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/redirects/setting-up-a-301-permanent-redirect-via-htaccess) and you will find exactly what you are looking for.